# How to use Web services in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

i am new to iphone programming and i am developing a app were i have to send some request to the server.At that movement if i lost the network then how to handle the request?

Comment: google web services tutorial iPhone

Comment: Advise as you are a NEW user on SO. **Try to google out your queries first** and then ask the question here only if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at of this url 
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/
this will help you